# Copy data from clipboard in postman

Tags: javascript, java, clipboard, postman

I use Postman a lot to test APIs. In addition, to authorize those tests I have to execute a program which generates a long signature which then, I copy and paste in Header. For one or two tests, it doesn't seem too much; but doing it for multiple APIs and like multiple times makes it really hectic and stupid.

Out of curiosity, I want to do this whole process automatically. I am able to copy that signature in clipboard(Using Toolkit and Clipboard in Java), but the issue is I don't know how to get from clipboard in Postman's pre-request script. I don't really know if it's possible or not. I apologize in advance if it's redundant or seems a bit stupid, because I haven't really found anything so far and it's purely my curiosity.
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

I use swagger.io instead postman for this issues. It allows to create really useful query interface for code documentation, testing and API inspecting. http://editor.swagger.io/#!/

Comment: It's good; even Postman gives you a test sandbox to write your code in JS; I just want to know how to access clipboard in there. The Swagger looks more like we have to write down a long script to test every api. Thanks though... Really appreciate it